# Login to my application using facebook credentials

Tags: android, facebook, fbconnect

This question might sound kiddish to you but I have to ask it.

I need to login from my application to my server using Facebook credentials. Is it actually possible? If the answer is yes, please guide me on this.

Comment: nice question I m also looking for something same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604969/seamless-facebook-login

Answer (score 2):

Facebook supports OpenID, which you can implement in your app.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246/

You can actually log in to stackoverflow using your facebook account as it uses OpenID as well.

Comment: Dear, as I mentioned in my query that I need to login to my server application from my android application and not to stackoverflow :) I hope I am clear with my query.

Comment: The last line was just an example of OpenID use ;) refer to http://openid.net/ to get started

Answer (score 0):

Rohit, what Will mean is you need to implement OpenID in your server. For that you need to write couple of pages in your web app, that will take care of OpenID Authentication.. then if you want your mobile users to login using OpneID, you can simple open that webpage (where you've implemented the OpenID) from within your application using some webview component or some other relevant component whatever it may be.. track user's navigation to success page to determine user is authenticated or not.

this is one way.. in other way.. there could be other ways as well..

good luck

Comment: Thanks J, will try this.. Really glad to see you here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this two link :

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands

From this two link you will get all the information for logging , sharing using facebook from your android application.