# Seamless Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an app which allow updates shared with Facebook.

The app is running f9, but what I actually want is to have login credentials to be provided from my UI Login page. Please guide whether it's possible from the Facebook perspective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Facebook SDK for Android supports single sign-on, so assuming the user has the official Facebook app installed and authenticated (very often the case these days) there is no need for them to provide their credentials to you app, they'll just click through a permissions page.  If your users have not authenticated with the Facebook app on their device they will need to provide them via Facebook's authentication dialog.  Your users will be more inclined to use the Facebook features in your app if you use this approach over a custom authentication UI.

You can find more information on the SDK on Facebook's [developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android).

Comment: i have signed in the offical app but the permission dialog doesnt show up.. any idea why ? the dialog opens and closes automatically :(

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [facebook  android tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android) on facebook's developer page. Hope thats what you are looking for.

- Salil.